# Decorators not changing dir()

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

Python decorators when used without

```
@functools.wraps(function)
```

changes the original function's `__doc__`,`__name__`,`help` which is understandable as decorator is simply

```
fun=decorate(fun)
```

but why doesnt it change dir(fun) for that function ? shouldn't it change as well ?

For example:

```
def wow(func):
    def __wow():
        return func()
    return __wow

@wow
def fun():
    print "yes"
fun.b=1
print fun.__name__
print dir(fun)
```

The output is

```
__wow   => name of decorator
[...   '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'b', 'func_closure', ...]
                                                    ^^
```

If you see here,when we print `name` it is of `decorator` but when we print `dir` its of `fun` as `b` is in there.So why is `b` there?Shouldnt it be `dir(decorator)` as fun.**name** gives that of decorator

Comment: What would you expect to be different?

Comment: @vks: you are applying both the attribute *and* `dir()` to the *decoration result*. You just set a new attribute on that object, **of course** `dir()` is going to include that.

Comment: I did also ask you to be explicit: You are only highlighting `'b'` in `dir()`. Did you not expect it to be there? Please explain what is surprising about the output and why.

Comment: Functions are objects. You returned `__wow` from the decorator, so Python assigned that object to `fun`. `fun` is *just a name* here, one that references the result of the decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to miss a crucial step in decorators. You do grasp that using a decorator `@decorate` on a function `fun` does this:

```
fun = decorate(fun)
```

but then don't follow through. `fun` is now bound to the return value of the decorator.

You said:

> Python decorators [...] changes the original function's `__doc__`, `__name__`, `help`

This is not true. The original, undecorated function is unchanged. It still has the same `__doc__`, the same `__name__`, etc. The *returned object* from the decorator, now bound to the original name, however, may well have a different name or docstring. After all, it may well be a *different object altogether*.

In your sample, you returned `__wow` from the decorator, so Python assigned that object to `fun`. `fun` is *just a name* here, one that references the result of the decorator. The *original* `fun` function is no longer available via that name; at *no point* are you inspecting the original, undecorated function here.

So using `dir()` on the **name** `fun` means it is applied to whatever `fun` is bound to now, and that is the `__wow` function produced by the decorator. Setting attributes on `fun`, sets attributes on that same function object. All attributes reflect this.

You may find it helpful to step through what Python does and visualise those steps. See this [Python Tutor visualisation](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20wow%28func%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__wow%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20func%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20__wow%0A%0A%40wow%0Adef%20fun%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%20%22yes%22%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false); it shows you what `fun` references in the end (and where the original function object ended up):

[image: references in the Python Tutor visualisation]

Answer (score 0):

`dir()` of a function is going to return something like this:

```
>>> dir(f)
['__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'func_dict', 'func_doc', 'func_globals', 'func_name']
```

How would you even tell if these were the attribute names of the original function, or of the wrapped function?  It's exactly the same list in either case.

Comment: if you add an attribute like `fun.c=1` then you can see for yourself

Comment: @vks: you really need to add a [mcve] to your function. *Show us the steps*, in code, and explain how the output that those steps produce do not match your expected output.